# how to display result of sql query with sum() of sql in php?

Tags: php

my sql code is `

```
$sql1 = "select sum(marks) from `result_master` where roll_no='$roll_no' and round='$round' GROUP BY `event_name`" ;
        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

`

I want to echo the result of sql query in php page using echo.
how can I do this?
thanks

Comment: use an alias in your query - `select sum(marks) as sum_marks ...`. Then after your `$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);` you do a loop using [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), ie. `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1){ echo $row['sum_marks']."<br />"; }`

Comment: Just noticed you have `$sql1 = ...`, but doing query on `$sql` -> `mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,It worked

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
  $sql1 = "select sum(marks) as total_marks from `result_master` where roll_no='$roll_no' and round='$round' GROUP BY `event_name`" ;
            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1){
         echo $row['total_marks'];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @sean suggested in comments  *you had `$sql1 = ...,` but doing query on `$result1-> mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`.*

Change it to `$result1 -> mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);`

Code should be like this:

```
$sql1 = "select sum(marks) AS Total_Marks from `result_master` where roll_no='$roll_no' and round='$round' GROUP BY `event_name`" ;
        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
echo "Total Marks = ".$row['Total_Marks ']."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql1 = "select event_name, sum(marks) sum from `result_master` where roll_no='$roll_no' and round='$round' GROUP BY `event_name`";
$result1 = mysqli_query($oDb, $sql1);

$aData = $result1->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($aData as $aRow){
    echo "Event: {$aRow['event_name']} -> count: {$aRow['sum']} \n";
}
```